# Error in for sentence robotframework

Tags: csv, automated-tests, robotframework

Hi im reading a CSV file (to get information from a WEB Service) with this values:

```
169233xxx
169129xxx
189925xxx
```

This is my keyword definition:

```
Carga RUTs
    [Documentation]      Carga lista de RUTs a validar desde archivo csv
    [Arguments]              ${file_name}

    ${data}=                 read csv file       ${file_name}
    [return]    ${data}
```

I catch this values in a for:

```
Consultar WS
    [Documentation]       Lee RUTs de archivo csv y consulta cada uno al Experto Original y Migrado.
    [Arguments]           ${data}

    ${rutsd}=       Set Variable        0


    Log To Console         .
    :FOR   ${element}        IN            @{data}
    \      ${rutsd}=    Fetch From Left     ${element}[0]       ;
    \      ${dvymas}=   Get Substring       ${element}[0]       -2


    \      Log To Console      Consultando RUT ${rutsd}...
    \      Run Keyword And Continue On Failure        WS Experto Orignal      ${rutsd}
```

At the moment of consulting....Appears for each "[" or "$apos" icon , i dont understand

```
<ns1:rut>['189925xxx </ns1:rut>

<ns1:rut>[$apos 189925xxx </ns1:rut>
```

At finally response:
Server raised fault: '1001: RUT no Válido' (translate DNI invalid(

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error?

Thanks,

Regards!!
EDIT:

To not creat a new post i have a new error, i modified

${element}[0] for @{element}[0]

The previous error was solved.

Now i have a new error:

List variable '@{element}' has no item in index 0

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error?

thanks again

Comment: In Python (Robot Framework is based on it), when you convert a `list` to a `str`ing, it will be surrounded by square brackets and its elements will be separated by commas,
 e.g. `['189925xxx', '169129xxx', '169233xxx']`. It appears that a variable's value is a `list` instead of a `str`ing. Also, `$apos` is just an escaped `'`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `${element}[0]` be `@{element}[0]`? I'm just looking at the docs, I haven't used Robot Framework yet.

Comment: Hi! @LocoLuis You are rigth good observation, is @{element}[0].

Comment: Now the robot response me this: List variable '@{element}' has no item in index 0.

Comment: Already solved!!! Thanks!!